# How can I fix an error creating newPost in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to make a new post, but I get "Followers matching query does not exist" as an error. I don't know how to fix it. Could someone help me to solve it?. Attached files.
All this done in Django.

models.py

```
class Followers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey (User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "followers")
    follower = models.ManyToManyField (User, related_name = "following")

    def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.user}"

class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField (max_length = 280)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField (default = timezone.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey (User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name = "posts")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField (User, related_name = "liked_posts")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.creator}"
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def newPost(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Post (content = request.POST['content'])    
        form.creator = Followers.objects.get (user = request.user)
        form.save()
    else:
        return render (request, "network/index.html")
    return HttpResponseRedirect (reverse("index"))
```

newPost.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="card-body" style="border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);">
    <strong><a style="font-size: 20px; color: black;" href="#">{{post.creator}}</a></strong> · <a style="font-size: 14px;">{{post.created_date}}</a>
    <a href="#" style="font-size: 14px; float: right;">Editar</a>
    <br>{{post.content}}
    <br>
    <a href="#" style="color: black;">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="m8 2.748-.717-.737C5.6.281 2.514.878 1.4 3.053c-.523 1.023-.641 2.5.314 4.385.92 1.815 2.834 3.989 6.286 6.357 3.452-2.368 5.365-4.542 6.286-6.357.955-1.886.838-3.362.314-4.385C13.486.878 10.4.28 8.717 2.01L8 2.748zM8 15C-7.333 4.868 3.279-3.04 7.824 1.143c.06.055.119.112.176.171a3.12 3.12 0 0 1 .176-.17C12.72-3.042 23.333 4.867 8 15z"/>
          </svg></a> <a>0</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `form.creator = Followers.objects.get (user = request.user)` to this: `form.creator = request.user`?

Comment: Follower with the current user does not exist, that's the problem. Also, I don't see any reason why you're using `Followers.objects.get (user = request.user)`, why just use `form.creator = request.user`